# Datetime of value 0 (as in MySQL) with boost::posix_time

Tags: c++, boost

In `boost::posix_time`, how can I get a timestamp (`boost::posix_time::ptime`) with value 0? (as the 0-0-0 0:0:0 MySQL datetime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. `posix_time::ptime` uses `gregorian::date` and according to reference [gregorian date](https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_class)

> The current implementation supports dates in the range 1400-Jan-01 to
>   9999-Dec-31.

so if you write to get min value of ptime

```
  boost::posix_time::ptime pt(boost::posix_time::min_date_time);
  cout << pt << endl; // 1400-Jan-01 00:00:00
```

you will see *1400-Jan-01 00:00:00* as output.